# Tracert shows WiFi Gateway Not LAN

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

- **Ethernet (Wired) Gateway**: `10.147.20.1`
- **WiFi Gateway**: `172.21.164.1`

On a Windows 10 v1709 device, based on the metric of 10, it would seem like LAN should have highest priority. However tracert goes through WiFi gateway.

Does this indicate there is a problem with priortisation of LAN traffic?

**route print** shows the following:

```
    Interface List 
74...d4 81 d7 34 02 35 ......Dell Giga Ethernet 
18...2a 16 ad 87 e8 f8 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter 
14...28 16 ad 87 e8 fc ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) 
12...28 16 ad 87 e8 f8 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 
11...d4 81 d7 ae 5d 75 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM 
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1 
44...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter 
42...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3 
45...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2 
43...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4 
=========================================================================== 

IPv4 Route Table 
=========================================================================== 
Active Routes: 
Network Destination Netmask Gateway Interface Metric 
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.21.164.1 172.21.164.68 198 
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.147.20.1 10.147.20.93 10 
10.147.20.0 255.255.254.0 On-link 10.147.20.93 266 
10.147.20.93 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.147.20.93 266 
10.147.21.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.147.20.93 266 
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306 
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306 
127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306 
172.21.164.0 255.255.252.0 On-link 172.21.164.68 355 
172.21.164.68 255.255.255.255 On-link 172.21.164.68 355 
172.21.167.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 172.21.164.68 355 
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306 
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 172.21.164.68 355 
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 10.147.20.93 266 
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306 
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 172.21.164.68 355 
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.147.20.93 266 
=========================================================================== 
Persistent Routes: 
None 

IPv6 Route Table 
=========================================================================== 
Active Routes: 
If Metric Network Destination Gateway 
1 306 ::1/128 On-link 
74 266 fe80::/64 On-link 
74 266 fe80::590c:5c25:e4a6:354f/128 
On-link 
1 306 ff00::/8 On-link 
74 266 ff00::/8 On-link 
=========================================================================== 
Persistent Routes: 
None



Tracing route to 10.14.206.162 over a maximum of 30 hops 

1 919 ms 970 ms 1061 ms 172.21.164.1 
2 2 ms 2 ms 1 ms 10.147.26.5 
3 253 ms 227 ms 10 ms 10.100.2.33 
4 14 ms 233 ms 13 ms 172.21.231.241 
5 5 ms 5 ms 5 ms 10.14.206.162 

Trace complete
```

Comment: 1) What was the destination address of the `tracert`? 2) Are the LAN and WLAN on the same device?  3) What happens if you `tracert` with the LAN and WLAN gateway as destination address?

Comment: did you try to change the priority of the network adapter manually (see my answer)?

Comment: I will try that what doesn't make sense though is according to routing table ethernet should have highest priority (it has metric of 10, wireless has metric of 298)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to two network adapters on your system (WLAN and Ethernet), which each have configured a different default gateway. And you wonder why the route goes through the wireless adapter and gateway instead of the wireless one!?

In Windows the last installed (as far as I can tell) network adapter gets the highest priority (event though the route print output lets you conclude s.th. different) - at least this was the case in my Win7 system but maybe a made a mistake interpreting it. When did the trick for me was to manually set the priority for the network adapters:

- Open Network and Sharing Center
- In the menubar click on "Advanced" and chooce "Advance Settings"
- Change the priority of the interfaces by moving them up or down

You find a more detailed explanation [here](https://www.itechtics.com/5-ways-automatically-turn-off-wifi-ethernet-lan-cable-connected/) (scroll down to "Set Network Adapters Priority").